# Are there way/s for me to extract data that only contain a certain values in sql?

Tags: sql

Are there way/s for me to extract data that only contain a certain values.
Ex:

```
Contact    Asset       Status
AB       1       Cancelled
AB       2       Cancelled
AB       3       Cancelled
AB       4       Cancelled
CD       5       Cancelled
CD       6       Active
CD       7       Cancelled
CD       8       Active
```

What I want to get are only those contacts that does contain cancelled assets ONLY (like Contact AB). And not those with both cancelled and active assets (like Contact CD).

Comment: What DBMS are you using? It's nice to be able to use the full range of syntax.

Comment: i am using a Network DBMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pure relational logic way is easier to understand, but will perform less well, requiring some kind of join to work. Let's satisfy the conditions

1. There is at least one status `Cancelled` for each `Contact`
2. But there are 0 statuses for that same `Contact` that aren't `Cancelled`

in a query like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   CS.Contact
FROM
   ContactStatus CS
WHERE
   CS.Status = 'Cancelled' -- at least one cancelled
   AND NOT EXISTS ( -- but there are none of...
      SELECT *
      FROM ContactStatus CS2 -- contacts in the same table
      WHERE
         CS.Contact = CS2.Contact -- for that same contact
         AND CS.Status <> 'Cancelled' -- that aren't cancelled
   )
;
```

But we can do this with an aggregate, that will take only a single scan of the table, by using a little thought:

```
SELECT
   Contact
FROM
   ContactStatus
GROUP BY
   Contact
HAVING
   Count(*) = Count(CASE WHEN Status = 'Cancelled' THEN 1 END)
;
```

Other aggregate expressions in the `HAVING` clause are possible, such as:

```
Count(CASE WHEN Status <> 'Cancelled' THEN 1 END) = 0 -- or Min()
Min(Status) = 'Cancelled' AND Max(Status) = 'Cancelled'
Max(CASE WHEN Status = 'Cancelled' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0
Sum(SELECT 1 WHERE Status <> 'Cancelled') = 0
```

All of these would do the trick in this case; pick the one that makes the most sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `group by` and a `having` clause:

```
select contact
from table t
group by contact
having min(status) = 'Cancelled' and max(status) = 'Cancelled';
```

This works for the data in your example.  If `status` could be `NULL` and you want to count that as a different value, then the logic would be slightly more complicated.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select contact from contacts a
where a.status = 'Canceled' AND contact = 'AB'
```